# mysqldumpで取得したダンプデータを確認すると、途中までしか取得できていない

Tags: mysql

**mysqldumpで全データ取得したのに途中までしかデータ取得できていない場合、原因として考えられることは？**
・発生要件等不明なのですが、印象としては、ある箇所以降全てが取得できない、みたいな感じです

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u -p --all-databases > out
```

---

**エスケープ**
・ダンプデータを取得する際、何らかのエスケープ処理をした方が良いことはありますか？
・例えば、SQL文を含む内容を格納しているときは何か特別な処理が必要みたいな…

**ロック**
・ダンプデータを取得する際、ロックがかかっていた場合はどうなるでしょうか？
・その箇所だけが取得できない？
・それ以降が取得できないわけではない？

---

**4/10 追記**
・もしかしたら正常にデータ取得できているかも

・取得したdumpデータ末尾が下記のようになっていたため、データ取得できていないと思っていたのですが、途中の方にも「Current Database: `データベース名1`」などがあり、そこでデータ取得できているようにも見えます。

```
--
-- Current Database: `データベース名1`
--

USE `データベース名1`;

--
-- Current Database: `データベース名2`
--

USE `データベース名2`;

--
-- Current Database: `データベース名3データベース名3`
--

USE `データベース名3`;

-- Dump completed on 日付
```

「Current Database: `データベース名`」は一回しか出てこないと思っていたのですが、「同じデータベース名のCurrent Database」がdumpデータの中に複数回書かれることはあるでしょうか？

また、データベース名3だけ、「Current Database: `データベース名3データベース名3`」となっている理由も分かりません

Comment: ログ等では特に問題は発生していないですか？

Comment: ログ確認しましたが、エラーはありませんでした

Comment: 標準出力をリダイレクトするのではなく、-r オプションを使って出力するのを試してみるのもいいかと。`mysqldump --single-transaction -u  -p --all-databases -r out` のように。

Comment: 試してみたら、「データベース名3データベース名3」となる現象が起きなくなりました。「-r オプション」と「標準出力」の関係が分からないのですが、「-r オプション」使用するから「 >」なしでも 出力OKなのでしょうか？　それとも「-r オプション」使用するから(プロシージャーなどのややこしそうな内容出力される可能性があるから？)「 >」なしの方が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: もしかして Windows 上で実行しているでしょうか。Windows のリダイレクトは正常に動作しないことがあるので、そのために -r オプションが用意されています。

Comment: CentOS7上で実行しています